# Cannot sh into rust image (made via multistage build)

Tags: bash, docker, rust, dockerfile

My Rust app dockerfile is as below, which is working fine

```
# Generate a recipe file for dependencies
FROM rust as planner
WORKDIR /app
RUN cargo install cargo-chef
COPY . .
RUN cargo chef prepare --recipe-path recipe.json

# Building our dependencies
FROM rust as cacher
WORKDIR /app
RUN cargo install cargo-chef
COPY --from=planner /app/recipe.json recipe.json
RUN cargo chef cook --release --recipe-path recipe.json

# Builder Image
FROM rust as builder
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=cacher /app/target target
COPY --from=cacher /usr/local/cargo /usr/local/cargo
RUN cargo build --release

# Final stage
FROM gcr.io/distroless/cc-debian11
COPY --from=builder /app/target/release/melt-agent-host /app/melt-agent-host
WORKDIR /app
```

But, I also want to bash into this image.

Is there any way to install bash in this distroless image ?

I also tried some other base images for the last stage that provides bash functionality,
Ex. alpine, busybox -- but those images, I am facing some other errors regarding `libgcc.so missing`

To sum up, I need a small size base image for the last stage which is compatible with Rust binary + also allows bash functionality.

Comment: You should be able to bash into any image. What exactly did you try? Should be something like docker exec -it <container_id_or_name> /bin/bash

Comment: In case of image it generally works with : docker run -it <image_id_or_name> /bin/bash OR /bin/sh
but this distroless image does not have sh -- as general alpine images do

Comment: If you want to avoid the `libgcc.so` issues on alpine, start from a `rust:alpine` image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final image is being built from a "distroless" base image.  This doesn't include any userspace tools – there probably isn't even a `/bin/sh` binary – and that's okay.  You won't be able to `docker exec` into this image and that's probably not a problem.

Your image just contains a set of shared libraries, some control files in `/etc`, and the one compiled binary (consider copying it into `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` so it's easier to run).  It's not clear to me what you'd do with a `docker exec` shell in this case.

If for some reason you do need a shell and the various tools that normally go with it (`ls`, `grep`, *etc.*) you need some sort of "normal" base image, not a "distroless" image or the special `scratch` image.  If you've built a static binary then it's possible the `busybox` image will work; if you have a dynamic binary, it's possible `alpine` will work as well (it will have a POSIX shell at `/bin/sh` but not GNU bash) but you might need to build your final image stage `FROM debian` or `FROM ubuntu`.

```bash
... all of your build stages ...

FROM debian:bullseye
COPY --from=builder /app/target/release/melt-agent-host /usr/local/bin
CMD ["melt-agent-host"]
```

Comment: debian:bullseye solved the issue with an 80MB docker image, Another solution which I found out later is : I used my dockerfile as it is, just added `COPY --from busybox /bin/* /bin/` -- This gave me the same result with a size of 29 MB !

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess you can just have a docker command in your docker file to COPY /bin/bash to somewhere, and then execute that. I don't know if bash depends on any shared libraries which you are missing, but that would be a starting point. If shared libraries are needed too, you'll have to copy those too.

I would also suggest that whatever you think you're gaining by having a distroless image, you aren't really gaining. Find a minimalist distro... and probably most of them for docker are anyway.